# How to cleanup an async funtion on componentDidUpdate using hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, react-hooks, lifecycle

I've a component upon whose mounting, I'm subscribing to a socket(async task) and I've to unsubscribe(async) in upon unmounting. When the component updates, I've to unsubscribe to the old socket and subscribe to the new one. I'm not sure how to do this using react hooks. Attaching a sample codesandbox for reference.

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-robinson-h0gq5

Comment: On `<Link to="/didMount">SimulateDidMount</Link>` you need to put other component and not the app component.. because when you switch the url the app component render again.. and actually did not unmount.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would like to implement the code within your sandbox but I think to call and async task within an effect you can do it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = async (msg, time) => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(msg);
    }, time);
  }
  timeout("subscribed to websocket", 2000);
  return () => {
    timeout("unsubscribed to websocket", 3000);
  };
}, [match]);
```

To use an `async` `await` within `useEffect` you need to declare it within the function and call it from there.